# Is there a low-code tool for an SQL analyst to share interactive views and graphical CRUD interfaces?

Tags: linux, sql, data-analysis, postgresql, gui-builder

I'm looking for a graphical interface around which to have live conversations about live data; something I can leave with a client for them to browse and perhaps update as they need, in their own time, without having to come back to me. I do a lot of ad-hoc reporting and data sets.

I'm good with SQL, and the data is in Postgres, and I don't have a good way of giving a nontechnical client a live view into the data. I could easily host a web interface, and I can code some, but I don't want to have to write a new app every week.

The status quo is CSV attachments. People are comfortable with it, but it is obviously not live, and there is a lot of back-and-forth that could be avoided if they could browse the data themselves. After a video conversation, or perhaps just an email or a few messages, they should be able to use it themselves.

I'm looking at 1-10 users per solution, and between a day and a month of usage before each solution is EOL.

Answer (score 0):

In a previous life I worked at a company that used [tableau](https://www.tableau.com/) for this.  I didn't get a chance to use it extensively, but it looked like it was a pretty powerful tool.